# HTTP proxy for RTSP server

Tags: node.js, networking, proxy, rtsp

I have an RTSP server with video streaming. I want to make a "proxy" server for it for external connections from multiple mobile devices. This server should be on Node.js.

Is it possible at all?

Could you please advice when I can get any information about my question?

Thanks,
    Pavel

Comment: You could proxy RTSP, but not via HTTP.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Generally, it should be Node.js server that forwards RTSP traffic for external clients.